# Import variables in python

Tags: python

I ran a python script to create a dict variable based on a database, and then I pickled this variable into disk file for later usage. Now I have a lot of feature classes which all need that variable to create different features. The thing is the dict variable is so large that cannot afford to import multiple times. I am wondering if there is a way I can unpickle and import that variable for only once, and then all feature class can share it?

Comment: why not define global variable assigne unpickled dict to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python will only import the module once. Any code that executes at load time will only be executed the first time a file imports the module.

Comment: I think this has the essence of a good answer, but is so brief that it is likely of little value to the OP (as well as many others lacking a solid Python background).